# I want to join two schemas into one schema in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to join two schemas into one because they both have almost same attributes and i want to use it for PostSchema that a user and also an owner can create and show their posts but i dont know how to achieve it

for example :

**UserSchema**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    gender: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: "User",
    },
});
```

**OwnerSchema**

```
const OwnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    gender: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Owner'
    },
    restaurant: RestaurantSchema
```

})

**PostSchema**

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    photo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    postedBy: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: *Combined user and owner*,
    },
    comments: [CommentSchema],
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your OwnerSchema - and modify your UserSchema to something like the below:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    gender: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: "User", //could be Owner when applicable
    },
    restaurant: RestaurantSchema, //could be null when role=User

});
```